# ¿Cómo puedo generar un XML válido de un SP para SAML2?

Tags: apache, saml, adfs

Me gustaría saber cómo implementar el protocolo SAML2 para mi SP personalizado, pero tengo algunas dificultades...

He intentado lo siguiente;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" entityID="http://www.mydomain.ext/#/secure">
  <SPSSODescriptor WantAssertionsSigned="true" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
   <AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="http://www.mydomain.ext/#/" isDefault="true"/>
    <KeyDescriptor>
     <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <ds:X509Data>
       <ds:X509Certificate>
        {my_x509_certificate_generated}
       </ds:X509Certificate>
      </ds:X509Data>
     </ds:KeyInfo>
    </KeyDescriptor>
   <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity</NameIDFormat>
  </SPSSODescriptor>
 </EntityDescriptor>
```

Necesito construir un fichero XML válido para poder federar mi SP con el IDP. ¿Qué me puede faltar?, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me auto-respondo.

Es necesario configurar el virtualhost para comunicarse con shibboleth, editar los archivos de configuración de shibboleth y finalmente visitar la URL "https://mydomain.ext/Shibboleth.sso/Metadata" para obtener el archivo de metadatos XML del SP. (Este archivo se genera automáticamente, no es necesario crear el archivo a mano)

PD: se recomienda tener un certificado SSL para el dominio.